# I can't get the app to go to the startup folder via python

Tags: python, startup

```py
import shutil
import pyuac
import os

from pyuac import main_requires_admin

@main_requires_admin
def main():
    directory = os.getcwd()
    source = directory + "\startup.py"
    target = r"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\startup.py"

    shutil.copyfile(source, target)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The Error**

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimError
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\pahwu\\Desktop\\project\\startup.py'

  File "C:\Users\pahwu\Desktop\project\Keylogger\startup.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
RuntimeError: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\pahwu\\Desktop\\project\\startup.py'
```

[image: picture of ide showing error]
I'm making my own application for which I'm also creating startup code. I think the code is correct, but it still says something is wrong with it?
Anyone help?

Comment: You need to post your code and the output, not only images... but once you do that your issue is simply stating your file cannot be found at the location you note for `target`. Are you running the code from the same directory the file is in?

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. I have edited your question to include the code and error as text. Please try to get closer to a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by editing your question.

Comment: Is the shown path to `startup.py` correct? If not, what is the right path and how is it related to the program (how could the program find it)?

Comment: code may run in different folder and `getcwd()` may gives you wrong path. Error shows  that it can't find  `C:\Users\pahwu\Desktop\project\startup.py` but it also shows that you run `C:\Users\pahwu\Desktop\project\Keylogger\startup.py` which has extra `Keylogger` in path. And maybe this makes problem. You may need `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` instead of `getcwd()` - to get folder with script.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was in many other question.

Code doesn't run in folder `project/Keylogger` but `project` but `getcwd()` doesn't gives folder with script (which means `project/Keylogger`) but `Current Working Directory` which here means `project`

You have to use

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

to get correct folder

---

And if you plan to use `pyinstaller` to create `exe` then you may need different method to get correct `directory`. But this you should find in documentation for `pyinstaller`

Comment: Again, please look for duplicates before answering common beginner FAQs.